# Class wasn't found and Select main class, I am using applet first time

Tags: java, applet

This is my code not showing GUI. I have tried many times please help me. My file name and class name is same.I don't know where to write main method and how to use it.This error , why???
Error: Main method not found in class mygui.MyGui, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
Java Result: 1

```
package guiexample;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;

public class GuiExample extends Applet{

    Label ageLabel;
    TextField age;
    Button click;
    Label result;
    @Override
    public void init(){
        ageLabel=new Label("Enter your age");
        age=new TextField();
        click=new Button();
        result=new Label("Over here");
        add(ageLabel);
        add(age);
        add(click);
        add(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: follow this [link](http://web.mit.edu/javadev/doc/tutorial/getStarted/applet/index.html)

Comment: Have you tried using google?

Comment: yes, but I am not getting my answer how to run this program.

Comment: @UUIIUI there is not answer to my question.

Comment: @UmarSharjeel try the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok try to create a new class ex: `AppletTest` and run it as application like this:

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Frame;

 public class AppletTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // define applet 
    GuiExample  myApplet = new GuiExample(); 
    // create frame with title
    Frame myFrame = new Frame("My Applet");

     myApplet.init();   
     // add applet to the frame
     myFrame.add(myApplet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     myFrame.pack(); 
     myFrame.setVisible(true); 
   } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform this basic debugging method:

Follow the [Hello World example](http://web.mit.edu/javadev/doc/tutorial/getStarted/applet/index.html) that @UUIIUI posted -- type in that example program and get it to run.

Then replace one line at a time with a line from your new program. You will quickly discover the problem.

When you discover your mistake, tell us what it was to help others with the same problem in future.